# Windows Phone 7 Mango, Alarm\Reminder notification

Tags: windows-phone-7, notifications, alarm

is it possible to customize the alarm\reminder notification? Delete\add buttons or override default behavior?

[image: notification]

Answer (score 3):

You can't actually override or add new buttons to a remainder. All you can do when you create a reminder from your code, is to set a NavigateUri, which defines where your user is taken if decides to click on the reminder.

A good (and also brief) explanation of what new reminder/alarm features are in Mango, Jessie Liberty has on his blog: http://jesseliberty.com/2011/04/29/whats-coming-in-mangoreminders/